# Are there any IFR training plugins / addons for Microsoft Flight Simulator or X-Plane?

Tags: flight-training, instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, flight-simulator, ifr-navigation

I am an IFR student, looking for software/plugins/add-ons/extensions to either Microsoft Flight Simulator or X-Plane to enhance the IFR training experience.

Specifically, I was wondering if there was an app that would evaluate my instrument approach in the simulator against the 'nominal' or idealized instrument approach based on the approach plate.

For example, it would evaluate the flight profile to see if I had stayed above the MDA; if I had followed the step-downs appropriately; if I had stayed within the required procedure turn completion distance, etc.

Is there any such software like this, or is specifically tailored towards IFR training?

Answer (score 2):

Both sims allow you to do a review of your flight where you can see both plan views and vertical profiles of the flight to analyze the results.  This can be especially useful when analyzing the results of attitude instrument flying like A and B patterns, etc.

CloudAhoy does allow integration of flights from X-Plane for review as well.

ATC is a bit better in games like FSX and Prepar3d, but I’d guess there are live ATC available in realistic multiplayer sessions of X-Plane as well.

One real pain in the butt about those Sims is just how out of date they are in terms of navigation databases, etc.  you really can effectively simulate approaches if you can load and practice the latest ones.

That being said the games are excellent to practice basic attitude instrument flying in as computers can simulate that very well sans the vestibular distractions which accompany flying in IMC.  You can also practice partial panel and other IFR emergencies here as well.

Comment: I agree, also navaids can be updated. FSX/Prepar3d for example https://www.aero.sors.fr/navaids3.html is good, for x-plane purchase them from Navigraph or Aerosoft. (https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/134304-navaid-updates/)